# How to change styles of a permanent component on React Route changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to change a piece of styling on the footer that is present at all pages of the website. **The changes must be present only on specific pages**. **Therefore, I need to somehow add a condition on what Routes the style should apply to the Footer.** How do I do it?

Here is a structure of my code:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="" component={} />
        <Route path="" component={} />
        <Route path="" component={} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
</Router>
```

I have tried useLocation hook. It would log the initial url I was in but not when I would change the page:

```
const location = useLocation()
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.pathname)    
}, [location])
```

My logic is to have a state for style that I pass in as a prop to the footer and based on what Route I am on, the state would change:

```
***
const [style, setStyle] = useState(null)
***
***
<Footer style={style} />
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Computing a matched route is derived "state", so don't use any local React state to hold this value. Use the [`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook and pass an array of paths you want to match against.

Example:

```
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Footer = () => {
  const match = useRouteMatch({
    path: ["/", "/someOtherPath"],
    exact: true
  });

  return (
    style={{ backgroundColor: match ? "green" : "red" }}
  );
};
```

When there is a current route path match then `match` will be a match object, otherwise it will be a null (*falsey*) value. You can conditionally apply any CSS (*`className` or `style`*) necessary.

[image: Edit how-to-change-styles-of-a-permanent-component-on-react-route-changes]

Answer (score 0):

**No need to save `pathname` in another state**

The `pathname` got from `useLocation()` is updated as state by React Router and can be used just like other states for conditional styling.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const footerStyle = {
    // Setting a different color for each route
    // Can also be classes or other custom styling
    color: {
      ["/"]: "pink",
      ["/product"]: "blue",
      ["/checkout"]: "purple",
      ["/user"]: "orange",
      //  Change these to your other routes
    },
  };

<Footer style={{ color: footerStyle.color[pathname] || "pink" }} />
```

The `footerStyle` can be stored somewhere else, for example in a `theme` file and be depend on conditions as well.

This example uses inline styles but classes can be added same way.

Hope this will help!